# Install cedar siding below overhang

Tags: exterior, siding, remodeling

I am installing cedar bevel siding and here is the top hitting overhang area

[image]

If you see the red line, my question is do I have to install the siding hitting that line? If so I need to cut around the lumber supporting the overhang

Or can I just install siding right below the overhang support?

**UPDATE**

This area originally has no softfit

[image]

But other areas have softfit and it is like below

[image]

(Same house, just different color at different time)

How to do this based on the photos?

Comment: What material are you doing for soffit? Normally you'd do the soffit first and you'd put your siding up to the soffit.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to finish the soffits, do as Fresh Codemonger indicated in comments. That will allow the gap of the soffit at the wall to be closed by the siding.

If you are not planning on finishing the soffits, add a 2X block between the overhang supports to create a straight line to finish the siding against. The added 2X which will also aid in the fastening of the soffit material if you choose to finish them later.

If you are planning on finishing the soffits, but it is not in the budget for now, temporarily fasten a scrap piece of material to the added 2X that is 1/8" thicker than what will be the soffit material thickness, so it can be removed when you are ready to add the finish soffits. The extra 1/8" will allow the soffit material to go in place over the siding and will only need a little caulk to seal the small gap left over.

Comment: Interesting ideas above. But now I am wondering if soffit is necessary or is it just cosmetic? I saw overhang without soffit and no problem at all for 8 years (that is the true time duration).

Comment: It is, IMO cosmetic, the overhangs will last without being finished, but it helps keep wasp nests down, giving them less corners to build their nests in. If it were my house, it would have finished soffits in a heartbeat. I have owned 3 houses in the past 30 years, 2 with finished soffits and barely a wasp nest, and one house with unfinished soffits and hundreds of wasp nests when we bought it as an "as is" foreclosure that was in turn key shape. We repainted it to sell it and that of course got rid of the nests.